# How to test multiple version of google chrome using chromedriver?

Tags: testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

selenium web-driver with java then how to use chrome driver for test their lower version of Google chrome

Comment: I can't understand your question. Could you clarify it?

Comment: I want test my website in multiple version of google chrome

Comment: You could use Selenium Grid for that.

Comment: Why?  Google chrome auto updates itself so the requirement sounds stupid.  I would push back on it.

Comment: Ardesco - it is true that Chrome auto updates. However, Google Chrome doesn't auto update on linux, that said it's possible to set-up group policies on a network to prevent chrome from auto updating on windows. I'm uncertain about chrome on other operating systems.

If you have a web app that needs to be locked down and validated, you can't have it updating itself in-between validation periods and chrome has made it possible to prevent such scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

From the official [wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver):

**Overriding the Chrome binary location**

You can specify the location of the Chrome binary by passing the "chrome.binary" capability, e.g. with a typical Chromium install on Debian:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

I suggest you try this approach - tell where the binary of lower version is and start ChromeDriver. Never tried it, but I think it might work

Comment: Code in answer no longer relevant to latest API's.

Answer (score 2):

You would use capabilities to point to the right binary file of the browser to be launced.But not all versions of chrome browser is supported by different versions of chromedriver. You will find exceptions stating that version of browser expected is greater or equal to 30.0.

For ex:- Chromium Browser(33.0.1729.0 )works fine with ChromeDriver 2.7 and not the with the older ones.

You can choose from all the chromedriver version available from the link below:-
http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Install chrome to custom location, be sure to turn off auto-update.  Use following code to use non-default binary.

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary("/path/to/binary");

    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(desiredCapabilities);
```