# Best way to test a web application for multiple versions of browser using Selenium automation?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ui-automation

I have been doing a research for quite a sometime but unable to find a good solution - therefore thought of asking on StackOverflow.

I have automated the testing using Selenium Webdriver for different browser but lately I had seen there were some issues which came for Chrome's older version - now, the question I had was if there is any way through which I could run the script for different versions of browsers e.g. test should run on Chrome 48 - Chrome 59 (covering majors versions only).

The two solution I got from my research was -

**1.** 
**Overriding the chrome binary location like the below link:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562068/6738995

I then started my research on how to download the binaries for Chrome and I found the official repo also - http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html

**2. Use Selenium Webdriver on cloud solution provider like BrowserStack or SauceLabs etc who provides multi-version-browser support**

Now, I want to exhaust all the options related to the 1st approach i.e. if there is no proper/easy way to implement the solution then I would have go for the 2nd approach.

The reason I am reluctant to go for 2nd approach is that I might loose control(I am speculating that there might be some restrictions on using that platform, I might be wrong and could only find out the try after tring that) and also there will be learning curve associated with this and I would also have to spend time & resources in order to stabilize with the chosen technology.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sauce labs providing multiple version of same browser. so that you triggered with any version, even beta version as well.

Comment: Yes - I mentioned that in the issue itself that if 1st doesn't work then I would have to choose 2nd solution for having automation in cloud using the product mentioned above.

Comment: You asked which is best? Then obviously Saucelabs/BrowserStack Approach. You can't maintain multiple versions. It would be hectic. Don't reinvent the wheel. If you have time and patience then you can go with approach 1

Comment: I understand the confusion - I had now edited the question. My aim is to exhaust all the options associated with approach 1 and then only move to the 2nd approach because I have already have the system built with 1st approach and I would have to spend more time & resources using 2nd approach.

Answer (score 0):

If resource isn't a concern/constraint for you, then you can use a Virtual Machine, like [VMWare](https://www.vmware.com/) and simulate separate test environments with different web browsers. However, if you are looking for `the best` solution, then you have to use Cloud solutions like SauceLabs or BrowserStack.

Comment: Yes, virtualization is one such solution but it requires a little more involvement than switching desired binaries of browsers. Btw, have you used Docker or have any idea about docker being used in current situation ?